# Why SvgImageSource Image, looks blurry than BitmapImage in UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

```
<StackPanel Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="20">
        <Image Width="24" Height="24" >
            <Image.Source>
                <BitmapImage UriSource="/Assets/AddComment.png"></BitmapImage>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
        <Image Width="24" Height="24" Stretch="None">
            <Image.Source>
                <SvgImageSource  UriSource="/Assets/AddComment.svg"></SvgImageSource>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </StackPanel>
```

[image]

I thought .svg image looks better than .png image .But here .svg image looks blurry.
I don't know, why .svg image looks blurry?
Is there any solution?

Comment: Please check if your svg content has been set available size.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand, what you are trying to say? Can you explain it?

Comment: How to share with You?

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuRPoWoQtgbHmSBjpGFVpOqnpSqB?e=fe1dju

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/SvgTest1) is code sample that you could refer.

Comment: Please check above code sample if you have any updates please comment below. Have a nice day!

Comment: yeah,sure.I will check and update it with you.

Comment: Have you tested the above code sample, does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why SvgImageSource Image, looks blurry than BitmapImage in UWP?

Please edit svg content with VS, and update the height and width property as **auto** like following.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="auto" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 24 24" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
```

And then apply a large value to  [`RasterizePixelHeight`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.svgimagesource.rasterizepixelheight?view=winrt-20348) and `RasterizePixelWidth` property for `SvgImageSource`. Please note you need to set Image control `Stretch` property as `Fill`

```
<Image
    Width="24"
    Height="24"
    Stretch="Fill">
    <Image.Source>
        <SvgImageSource
            RasterizePixelHeight="240"
            RasterizePixelWidth="240"
            UriSource="/Assets/AddComment.svg" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

**Top is png bottom is svg**

[image]

Comment: Yeah. Its working. But, What's the reason of setting Rasterization Pixel value to High?

Comment: because we have set the svg height and width as auto, so we need specific Rasterization Pixel value to render available size.  more big value, more clear image